# Asp MVC6 anchor taghelper area

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, anchor

I'm new to asp mvc6 and I'm just making a sample web site... something similar to my old project (mv5)

I'm stuck with linking views from different areas and I can't find any example how to annotate anchor tag with taghelpers...

I checked this ([anchor tag helper](http://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2015/06/01/mvc-6-anchor-tag-helper.aspx)) post about anchors and tried this:

```
<a asp-area="MyRegion" asp-controller="Test" asp-action="Index">TestLink</a>
```

Can anyoune please help me?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: what is the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use **asp-route-area** instead of **asp-area**. And make sure the class definition for your controller has an **[Area("MyRegion")]** attribute or it won't resolve correctly and you'll end up with a **?area=MyRegion** instead.

Comment: a verry late response,...
but yes, it worked :)
Thank you very much